# How can I ensure each instrument and vocals are audible during band rehearsal?

Tags: sound, band, live-sound, rehearsal, studio

I have read a lot of advice on how to mix live performances and recording of bands. I have learned about making sure instruments are isolated in their frequency ranges during performances so that each is audible.

However I do not know how I can apply this to a studio rehearsal environment. e.g. in rehearsal there may be two guitarists, a bass player with their own amplifiers, a drummer and a vocalist amplified by a PA system.

I don't know of a way to ensure that the frequencies are isolated.

What are the practical steps or tools I can use to ensure that each instrument can be heard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In band rehearsal, the mix typically isn't really good anywhere in the room. And it needn't be, because since everybody has their own amp, there's very good *spatial separation*. Which is almost as useful as frequency separation for making everything audible. To fully exploit this, make sure everybody hears everybody else from a different direction, i.e. place no two amps too close.

Apart from that, of course nobody should be so loud that they grossly overpower everybody else. Everybody should hear themselves a bit better than the others, to prevent the "more me, must go louder!" impetus. It's particularly helpful to place cabinets / PA speakers close to *the ear* of who uses the thing as their monitor, i.e. no small amps blasting the guitarist's feet...
In particular for bass, it often helps to put the amp a bit further away: when standing right before the amp, you can *feel* it a lot, but don't *hear* much at all.